# Are the real and imaginary parts of a positive definite complex matrix, also positive definite matrices?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

If a complex matrix $X=X_1 +jX_2$ is positive definite, what can we say about its real and imaginary parts? Are they also positive definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real part? Always. Imaginary part? Never.

The real part of a positive definite matrix $A$ is just the average of two positive definite matrices $A$ and $\bar{A})$ and hence it is positive definite.

The imaginary part of a positive definite matrix is a matrix with a zero diagonal. Hence it cannot be positive definite.

Comment: This answer leaves open the possibility that the imaginary part of a positive definite matrix is positive *semi*definite, but this is also not true (unless, trivially, the imaginary part is zero): the imaginary part of a positive definite matrix is a real skew symmetric (i.e., anti-symmetric) matrix, and the eigenvalues of such a matrix are [strictly imaginary and come in complex conjugate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory), i.e., the eigenvalues are pairs of the form $i\mu$ and $-i\mu$ for real $\mu$.

Comment: @JessRiedel Thanks, but the imaginary part of a PD matrix can be positive semidefinite. This occurs when the imaginary part is zero.

Comment: Thanks @user1551, I neglected to address that trivial case and edited my comment to fix.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $X_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $X_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $X=X_1+iX_2$ is positive definite, but $X_2$ isn't.